# SQL select script to create team

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I want select script to display team with no repeat.

Below is the table data in TableA.

```
ID  COL1
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
```

**Expected Result**

```
TeamColA TeamColB
A        B
A        C
A        D
B        C
B        D
C        D
```

If there are more records in table then select script should be automatically take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a self join:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col1
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.col1 < t2.col1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select a.COL1, b.COL1
from TableA a 
    inner join TableA b
        on a.ID < b.ID
```